# is onTouchStart exactly equivalent to onMouseDown and onTouchEnd exactly equivalent to onMouseUp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, mouseevent, touchscreen

It is not behaving the same for me on a range slider.

The code that is triggered for the onMouseDown and the onTouchStart is exactly the same code and same for the end and up.

So are they exactly equivalent or are there differences?

Answer (score 1):

The event order triggered is (most of the cases)

```
touchstart  > touchmove >  touched > mousemove > mousedown > mouseup > click
```

So **`No`** they are not the same or equivalent, but can be considered to perform similar functionality on different devices

Answer (score 0):

`onTouchStart` is used on touch screen surface whereas,
`onMouseDown` is used when a user presses a mouse button over an element